# Unable to select three objects to join

Tags: modeling

I have been working through a tutorial, and when instructed to select three objects to join them I can only select two of them.  When I try to select the third it toggles the first two off. When I select either of the first two both are selected. What setting have I changed maybe.

Comment: Make sure you are holding down the shift key while selecting all the three objects.